# construct std::vector<int> with initial size without setting them to 0

Tags: c++, vector

this

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a(5);
    // a.resize(5) has the same effect

    fmt::print("{}\n", a.size());
    a.push_back(2);
    fmt::print("{}\n", a.size());

    return 0;
}
```

will output:
5
6

i want to give the vector an initial size, but when doing so with a int vector, all those values are going to be set to 0, and i just want them to be nothing, so that when i push_back() to the vector, it does not resize, adding the element after those useless zeroes.

Comment: Are you looking for [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)?

Answer (score 2):

Simply declare `std::vector<int> a;` without the size parameter.

C++ does not provide a method to construct a vector with a given capacity (cf. Java).

Consider using `reserve` to be an over-optimisation, and let the C++ standard library resize the vector for you when it needs to. Unless performance profiling tells you otherwise, trusting the default behavior is unlikely to have a measurable effect.

Comment: `reserve` can provide a non-optimization benefit in some cases, as it means the capacity doesn't change unless you exceed the reserved size (or call other capacity changing functions like `shrink_to_fit`); if you stay within the reserved capacity, you don't invalidate iterators and references, which can be of practical benefit even if optimization isn't a concern. It's not necessarily premature optimization.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I find that code that relies on vectors not resizing is rather brittle. I prefer to use a `std::array` for such things.

Comment: Yeah, not claiming it's a great idea, just that it's a reasonable use case. `std::array` doesn't allow lazy initialization (and lacks cheap move/swap semantics), where a pre-`reserve`d `std::vector` can do so (and has cheap move/swap semantics).

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing the `vector` with a *size* of 5 `int`s already placed into it up front, where their default value will all be 0 (you can specify a different value in the constructor).  Then you are pushing a 6th `int` into the vector, growing its *size*.  That is why you get the result you are seeing.

What you are asking for requires setting the vector's *capacity* (how many items it can physically hold) rather than its *size* (how many items are valid within the *capacity*).  However, there is no way to set the *capacity* during construction while keeping the *size* at 0.  You would have to explicitly call the [`vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) method after construction, eg:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.reserve(5);

    fmt::print("{} {}\n", a.capacity(), a.size());
    a.push_back(2);
    fmt::print("{} {}\n", a.capacity(), a.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 0
5 1
```

The `vector` will now have an initial *capacity* of 5 `int`s, and it will not reallocate its array until a push would cause its new *size* to exceed that *capacity*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `reserve` function instead of `resize`.

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a; // construct the vector using the fefault ctor
    a.reserve( 5 ) // now a has a capacity of 5 but no elements have been initialized

    fmt::print( "Capacity: {} --- Size: {}\n", a.capacity(), a.size() );
    a.push_back( 83 );
    fmt::print( "Capacity: {} --- Size: {}\n", a.capacity(), a.size() );

    return 0;
}
```

Using `resize(size_t n)` will set both capacity and size to **n** but using `capacity(size_t n)` does not alter the size of the vector but it *may* increase the size of allocated space.

Also, Note that `capacity(size_t n)` can **not** decrease the capacity. In order to do that you need to use either `resize(size_t n)` or `shrink_to_fit(size_t n)` based on what you want to do.